# Which UX KPI's to measure with hardware products?

Tags: ux-integration, hardware

One of my tasks in my workplace is to measure the UX efficiency of our product ([collaborative robots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobot)) and one of my main challenges is to figure out **how to measure the customer experience when interacting with the robot.** (You can control the robot through a UI on a tablet or by manually grabbing the robot and moving him.)

The challenge with this is that, although I can analyse how the user performs when interacting with the UI on the tablet, I can't measure how the user deals with the robot himself. (Problems might arise because the robot is heavy, hard to move, etc.)

We conduct field visits to customers but I'm looking for methods that are more scalable and able to be done remotely, if possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you test something remember that there is quantitative stuff (measuring ***what*** the user does) and qualitative stuff (measuring ***why*** the user does it, and ***how*** they feel about it).

If you just stick to quantitative measures, you are missing out on a lot of valuable insights about the user's **experience**.

So when the person is interacting with the robot:

- Did they get excited or were they disappointed?
- Did they find it easy to get up and running or was it convoluted and confusing?
- Will they recommend to friends?

So it is just as important to answer these qualitative measures alongside quantitative measures like:

- how long it took them to get going
- how long did it take them to complete the task
- How many clicks/taps did they make
- how many mistakes they made

There are limits and challenges to doing this remotely - you can miss what is going on in the environment, which might be important for this solution.

Comment: Nice points but I'm wondering if reaction can be measured on a more scalable way rather than having an X amount of field visits or focus groups. 
The example I remember is how phone makers do this analysis on a large scale and on various kinds of testers (varying from age, geographic location, gender, etc)

Comment: Remote testing can answer "what did they do?" questions, but the main challenge with remote testing is answering some of the "why did they do that?" questions. The only way to answer "why did they do that?" questions remotely, is if you moderate the remote testing, will you be doing this?

Comment: Nielsen has said for years that [you usually need only 5 users](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/how-many-test-users/) to test your system to get good, usable usability data. It wouldn't surprise me if that also applies to hardware testing. You mention scalability and remote testing, but you might not need that.